# reload form from another form in vb

Tags: vb.net

I have two forms, first `form1` contains a listview in which some data are there and there is a button 'Change' which on clicking this button another form `form2` is opening with all datas of listview (in form1), I am changing the data and clicking save button, datas are modified in the database and form2 is closed but I am not able to see change in form1, when I close form1 and then reopen it then only I see the modified data

Is there any way to see modified data without reopening of form1.

in form 2 I used

```
 Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
  ..............  ' steps to modify data and save in database
  form1.show()
  me.close()
  End Sub
```

Comment: You need to update/reload your ListView to see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

see you are just showing `form1` so you are not reloading the data if you want to see the changes you can reload the data or create new instance of `form1` , but as an enhancement , create a **function** that reload's the list and put a `delegate` on it then pass it to `form2` when the form makes any change just `invoke` the delegate and it will reload your data instantaneously. 
Sweet huh :)